# Connecting to dropbox via python over a proxy

Tags: python, https, proxy, dropbox, socks

i am trying to connect to a Dropbox Account with python 2.7.4 (x64 win7) and their guide [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/authentication#python) helped me a lot. However when i am behind a proxy and this code just won't do it. 
(From home the code works great, where i am not behind the proxy)

I tried to fiddle with the urllib2 and httplib which are used in the **dropbox/rest.py** but had no luck. I know i have to change the Connection Code but i am not sure how to do this for a Socket.

**dropbox/rest.py** [line:99]

```
def create_connection(address):
    host, port = address
    err = None
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
        af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
        sock = None
        try:
            sock = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)
            sock.connect(sa)
            return sock

        except socket.error, _:
            err = _
            if sock is not None:
                sock.close()

    if err is not None:
        raise err
    else:
        raise socket.error("getaddrinfo returns an empty list")
```

i always get the error: [Errno 10060] SocketError.
I don't really know a lot about networks and ports but i know i can connect to the proxy on port 3128 and dropbox waits on 433. For that matter i had trouble connecting to any **https://**-adress. So i found this code:

```
proxyHost = 'www.myProxy.adress.com'
proxyPort = 3128
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(proxyHost, proxyPort)
conn.request("POST", "https://www.google.com")
```

Which works but i lack the skills to adapt this to the socket connection. Especially confusing is that i give the proxyAdress to the connection and have to write the Request in the header or somewhere, compared to the usually way, where i can give the final-Adress to the connection.

This was when i read about [SOCKS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pysocks/) for python and tried them but i could not easily replace the socket code with the new "*socksocket*" for which a proxy can be set with:

```
import socks
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5,"www.myProxy.adress.com")
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
urllib.urlopen("https://www.google.com/")
```

Any help, how to change the create_connection func of the rest.py to work with a proxy is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue myself and in searching for a solution came across this post.

I've managed to resolve this with a minor modification to the dropbox/rest.py code.

In the RESTClientObject class's **init** method change:

```
   self.pool_manager = urllib3.PoolManager(
        num_pools=4, # only a handful of hosts. api.dropbox.com, api-content.dropbox.com
        maxsize=max_reusable_connections,
        block=False,
        timeout=60.0, # long enough so datastores await doesn't get interrupted
        cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
        ca_certs=TRUSTED_CERT_FILE,
        ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1,
    )
```

to:

```
    self.pool_manager = urllib3.ProxyManager(
        num_pools=4, # only a handful of hosts. api.dropbox.com, api-content.dropbox.com
        maxsize=max_reusable_connections,
        block=False,
        timeout=60.0, # long enough so datastores await doesn't get interrupted
        cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
        ca_certs=TRUSTED_CERT_FILE,
        ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1,
        proxy_url ='http://yourproxy.com:proxyport/',
    )
```

Note the change to use ProxyManager rather than PoolManager and the addition of the proxy_url.

There are ways to authenticate against the proxy, but I haven't explored those.  So this will only work if you've already authenticated via Internet Explorer or similar.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Can't you just set the http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables? Does that not work?